# std::list::clear causes segfault (invalid memory address)

Tags: c++, stl

I have the ObjRecRANSAC class which has following std::list member:

```
    std::list<OrientedPointPair> sampled_oriented_point_pairs_;
```

OrientedPointPair is a class defined inside ObjRecRANSAC as follows:

```
    class OrientedPointPair
    {
        public:
          OrientedPointPair (const float *p1, const float *n1, const float *p2, const float *n2)
          : p1_ (p1), n1_ (n1), p2_ (p2), n2_ (n2)
          {
          }

          virtual ~OrientedPointPair (){}

        public:
          const float *p1_, *n1_, *p2_, *n2_;
    };
```

Once the ObjRecRANSAC class is constructed.  A call to `sample_oriented_point_pairs_.clear()` is made which causes a seg fault.

I tried to use gdb to debug the error and here is what I got:

```
print sampled_oriented_point_pairs_
$4 = {<std::_List_base<pcl::recognition::ObjRecRANSAC::OrientedPointPair, std::allocator<pcl::recognition::ObjRecRANSAC::OrientedPointPair> >> = {
    _M_impl = {<std::allocator<std::_List_node<pcl::recognition::ObjRecRANSAC::OrientedPointPair> >> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_List_node<pcl::recognition::ObjRecRANSAC::OrientedPointPair> >> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_node = {
        _M_next = 0x3f7d70a4, _M_prev = 0x0}}}, <No data fields>}
(gdb) s
std::list<pcl::recognition::ObjRecRANSAC::OrientedPointPair, std::allocator<pcl::recognition::ObjRecRANSAC::OrientedPointPair> >::clear (this=0x7fffffffdb38) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_list.h:1197
1197            _Base::_M_clear();
(gdb) s
std::_List_base<pcl::recognition::ObjRecRANSAC::OrientedPointPair, std::allocator<pcl::recognition::ObjRecRANSAC::OrientedPointPair> >::_M_clear (this=0x7fffffffdb38) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/list.tcc:70
70        _Node* __cur = static_cast<_Node*>(this->_M_impl._M_node._M_next);
(gdb) print __cur
$5 = (
    std::_List_base<pcl::recognition::ObjRecRANSAC::OrientedPointPair, std::allocator<pcl::recognition::ObjRecRANSAC::OrientedPointPair> >::_Node *) 0x7a6c60
(gdb) print *__cur
$6 = {<std::__detail::_List_node_base> = {_M_next = 0x50a330, _M_prev = 0x7fff00000000}, _M_data = {_vptr.OrientedPointPair = 0x0, 
    p1_ = 0x7fffef9364d8, n1_ = 0x1b280e0, p2_ = 0x1ed2f00, n2_ = 0x1ed2f00}}
(gdb) s
71        while (__cur != &this->_M_impl._M_node)
(gdb) s
73        _Node* __tmp = __cur;
(gdb) s
74        __cur = static_cast<_Node*>(__cur->_M_next);
(gdb) print __cur
$7 = (
    std::_List_base<pcl::recognition::ObjRecRANSAC::OrientedPointPair, std::allocator<pcl::recognition::ObjRecRANSAC::OrientedPointPair> >::_Node *) 0x3f7d70a4
(gdb) print *__cur
** Cannot access memory at address 0x3f7d70a4 **
(gdb) print &this->_M_impl._M_node
$8 = (std::__detail::_List_node_base *) 0x7fffffffdb38
(gdb) s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004c1608 in std::_List_base<pcl::recognition::ObjRecRANSAC::OrientedPointPair, std::allocator<pcl::recognition::ObjRecRANSAC::OrientedPointPair> >::_M_clear (this=0x7fffffffdb38) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/list.tcc:74
74        __cur = static_cast<_Node*>(__cur->_M_next);
```

Clearly this is the problem: **Cannot access memory at address 0x3f7d70a4**

What I also don't understand is why is the address of `__cur` initially set to  `0x7a6c60` before the execution of line 70 when current hasn't even been declared at this point.  Also printing `*__cur` before execution of line 70 seems to return a value which is also a surprise.

The sampled_oriented_point_pair_ is simply declared in the class and it is not initialized in the constructor.  Could this be the problem?  However, this code used to work before?

Comment: Are you certain that lifetime of the `float` variabless your `OrientedPointPair`objects point to is longer than the lifetime of the `OrientedPointPair` objects?

Comment: the problem seems to be that _M_next should point back to the node itself since this is an empty list but instead its pointing to an invalid memory address.  I am guessing because of the line `while (__cur != &this->_M_impl._M_node)`

Comment: Can you show us your code, it's very likely that the segfault is not the result of the clear, but the result of a previous out of bounds write, overwriting sample_oriented_point_pairs_.